# How to fill HTML with JSON in a functional way

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, functional-programming

I am trying to understand the approach of functional programming. From what I understand, it is basically to encapsulate everything into a function and pass them around. Now for my example I try to load data from a RESTApi and render it into the DOM:

```
const storyElement = function (): HTMLElement {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'stories';
    return div;
};

const spinnerElement = function (): HTMLElement {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'spinner';
    div.innerHTML = `<svg class="spinner" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="20" height="20">
                        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="42" transform="rotate(-90,50,50)" />
                    </svg>`;
    return div;
};
```

I have two divs, one for the Stories and one for the loading-icon. If the content is rendered, the icon should disappear.

```
function getAllStories(callback): void {
    makeRequest(baseUrl(), (res) => spawn(res, callback));
}

function spawn(content, callback): void {
    content = JSON.parse(content);

    if (content instanceof Array === false) {
        content = [content];
    }

    content.forEach(elm =>
        storyElement().innerHTML += `<h1>${elm.title}</h1>
                                     <div class="story-info">
                                        <i>ID: Post-${elm.id}</i>
                                     </div>
                                     <p>${elm.body}.</p>`
    );
    console.log(content);
    callback();
}

function displayFinished(): void {
    spinnerElement().style.display = 'none';
    document.body.innerHTML += '<div>All done!</div>';
}
```

Now when I execute `getAllStories` the console prints out the result, but the content does not render in the DOM:

```
document.body.appendChild(storyElement());
document.body.appendChild(spinnerElement());

getAllStories(displayFinished);
```

Does anyone have a clue why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @dnt I have solved my issue. The solution is to create an element and to nest this functionality: get data from RESTAPI => spawn it into the DOM => finish displaying loading icon.

```
function createElm(className: string, innerHTML?: string): Node {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = className;
    if (innerHTML) {
        div.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    return div;
}

function getAllStories(callback): void {
    makeRequest(baseUrl(), callback);
}

function spawn(content, html, callback): void {
    content = JSON.parse(content);

    if (content instanceof Array === false) {
        content = [content];
    }

    content.forEach(elm =>
        html.innerHTML += `<h1>${elm.title}</h1>
                                     <div class="story-info">
                                        <i>ID: Post-${elm.id}</i>
                                     </div>
                                     <p>${elm.body}.</p>`
    );

    callback();
}

function displayFinished(html): void {
    html.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.innerHTML += '<div>All done!</div>';
}

const stories = createElm('stories');
const loadingIcon = createElm('spinner', `<svg class="spinner" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="20" height="20">
                        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="42" transform="rotate(-90,50,50)" />
                    </svg>`);

getAllStories(res =>
    spawn(res, stories, () =>
        displayFinished(loadingIcon)));
```

I am now just asking myself if there is a better soultion for my approach. It seems wrong to me, not using simple variables for dom-elements...

Comment: You should not modify DOM in a loop (`html.innerHTML += ...`), that causes layout re-calculation every single time. Also, using plain string interpolation like that opens you up all kinds of nasty issues like invalid HTML and XSS attacks. Would recommend using some kind of templating library.

Comment: It is not a real-life project just try to test out the callback approach, did not want to take it that far, but thanks for the advice! :)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are calling `storyElement()` in your `.forEach`, new element is created. You never changed your original element, that you attached to the DOM.